# Chrome - CSS border not working correctly

Tags: css, google-chrome, colors, border

I have an inline-block element with text and I want to have it dashed underline. Since I can't set this with `text-decoration` property, I add `border-bottom` to the element. But it acts quite strange in Chrome - the color of border is not I specify, it looks like a bit transparent. It looks perfect in IE and Firefox however. If I do not specify bottom border and just draw all four borders, everything looks correctly. I've also tried to wrap the element into another `div` and it gave no result. Besides, problem disappears when I increase `line-height` to, say, 3.1 and more, but border is obviously very far from text. I use the latest version of Chrome. I also attach screenshots to describe the problem.

CSS code:

```
.contacts_link-to-map {
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #FFD4F3;
    font-size: .8em;
    line-height: 1.1;
}
```

Here is a link to CodePen: http://codepen.io/GALLlblSH/pen/MwwRNB?editors=110

Border in Moz/IE:

[image]

Border in Chrome:

[image: http://imgur.com/1UdJvNE]

UPDATE: I found a solution, but it is really strange and does not seem to be linked with the issue. I just removed `margin: 5px 0 0 0;` line in `.contacts_social` style and everything got well. Does someone know what is reason of this behaviour?

Comment: It is better to also share the [codepen](http://codepen.io/) or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) link with the existing code.

Comment: Added link to CodePen

Comment: Couldn't reproduce, sorry.  Maybe try setting the color with 100% opacity using rgba();

Comment: In Mac, Chrome, Firefox renders the border as is. Which OS are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Try add this above your css line for border-bottom

```
 border-top: 1px dashed rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

It's a bit of a hack, but seems to fix your issue

[Codepen revised css](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNNWYq)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. It seems that when bottom border is the only visible (no matter that there are other borders exist) it looks more transparent.